# Get the next distinct record(s) from a table using pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table with the below data

[image]

and I am trying to get the next distinct set of values (next 3 values) as shown below

[image]

I have tried using the lead functions but ended up with the below result

[image]

```
spark.sql("select *,\
            coalesce(lead(page, 1) over (partition by id order by date_time asc), 'Exit') as next_pagename1, \
            coalesce(lead(page, 2) over (partition by id order by date_time asc), 'Exit') as next_pagename2, \
            coalesce(lead(page, 3) over (partition by id order by date_time asc), 'Exit') as next_pagename3, \
        from temp").show()
```

Can anyone please let me know what I am missing here?

EDIT:

Updated the example data

Comment: You should remove the columns with the duplicate pages before running the sql

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I am struggling with. Any thoughts on how I can accomplish it?

Answer (score 0):

You can group the data by `id` and `page` and take the minimal value of `date_time`. After that you can use the sql that you have already provided:

```python
spark.sql("""with data as (
               select id, page, min(date_time) as date_time from 
               temp group by id, page)
        select data.id, data.page,
            coalesce(lead(data.page, 1) over (partition by data.id 
                    order by data.date_time asc), 'Exit') as next_pagename1,
            coalesce(lead(data.page, 2) over (partition by data.id 
                    order by data.date_time asc), 'Exit') as next_pagename2,
            coalesce(lead(data.page, 3) over (partition by data.id
                    order by data.date_time asc), 'Exit') as next_pagename3
         from data""").show()
```

Output:

```
+---+-----+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| id| page|next_pagename1|next_pagename2|next_pagename3|
+---+-----+--------------+--------------+--------------+
|123|login|         page1|         page2|         page5|
|123|page1|         page2|         page5|         page3|
|123|page2|         page5|         page3|          Exit|
|123|page5|         page3|          Exit|          Exit|
|123|page3|          Exit|          Exit|          Exit|
+---+-----+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

---

With the new data, you can collect the next pages into an array (called `data` in my code) and then filter the array (`filtered_data`).

```python
spark.sql("""
with data as (
    select page,
    array(lead(page, 1)over (partition by id order by date_time asc),
        lead(page, 2)over (partition by id order by date_time asc),
        lead(page, 3)over (partition by id order by date_time asc),
        lead(page, 4)over (partition by id order by date_time asc),
        lead(page, 5)over (partition by id order by date_time asc)) as next
    from temp),
filtered_data as (
    select page,
    filter(transform(next, (x,i) -> if(i=0 or x!=next[i-1], x, null)), x -> x=x) as next
    from data)
select page, 
    ifnull(next[0], 'Exit') as next_pagename1, 
    ifnull(next[1], 'Exit') as next_pagename2, 
    ifnull(next[2], 'Exit') as next_pagename3
    from filtered_data    
""").show(truncate=False)
```

Output:

```
+-----+--------------+--------------+--------------+
|page |next_pagename1|next_pagename2|next_pagename3|
+-----+--------------+--------------+--------------+
|login|page1         |page2         |page5         |
|page1|page2         |page5         |page3         |
|page2|page2         |page5         |page3         |
|page2|page5         |page3         |page2         |
|page5|page3         |page2         |Exit          |
|page3|page2         |Exit          |Exit          |
|page2|page2         |Exit          |Exit          |
|page2|Exit          |Exit          |Exit          |
+-----+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

When collecting the data in the first array, I use a "lookahead" of 5. This number can be increased if necessary by adding more elements to the array.

Comment: Thanks @werner! Unfortunately, your code wouldn't work where there are records for the same page later. Please see the updated examples in my post.

Comment: @kkumar I have added another possible solution